# Get UIImages from UIViewAnimation

Tags: ios

I have some simple animation code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// The transform matrix
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
image.transform = transform;

// Commit the changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It is possible to get each frame of the animation as uiimages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get each frame as UIImages (except if you used `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` at a very fast rate on the frame of the animating view, and I'm not even sure if that would work), but with a Core Animation, you can access the `presentationLayer` property of a CALayer, which (from the [CALayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)):

> Returns a copy of the layer containing all properties as they were at the start of the current transaction, with any active animations applied.

Hope this helps!